# Identification of this fly?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

So I find these flies every year in my mulch, and I've never seen them anywhere else. The mulch becomes full of their larvae, which I feed to my toad and lizards. There are so many that you can hear them moving. The adults are black, look like a wasp or hornet, and have a curious green patch on the underside of their abdomen, which is a clear patch showing some kind of liquid. The larvae are brown and have a little hair on them.

[image]

[image]

It's about one inch I think maybe a little less. I hope the quality is good enough, because I used my iPod for the picture and you can't do macro with it. Also, I live in Hillsboro Oregon. I am near a small forest and in the suburbs.

Comment: A **picture** (but I think you need more reputation first so I've upvoted) and **location** would both be very useful for this. also some idea of size.

Comment: Hi Keivn, to show us the pictures you have first upload them to a website such as imgur.com and [edit] your post to include the links the site gives you.  Once you have 10 reputation you will be able to this in one step on this site.

Comment: You now have more than 10 reputation and can include images in your post.

Comment: This should be a comment, but rep is too low. Question: what do you put in your mulch pile? That would help ID the fly.

Comment: These links might help: [Wasps](http://www.animalphotos.me/insect3-wasp.htm) and [BugGuide](http://bugguide.net/node/view/59/bgpage).

Answer (score 7):

Black soldier fly *Hermetia illucens*[image: Black soldier fly.]. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermetia_illucens

There is a good key to the Dipteran families [here](ftp://delta-intkey.com/britin/dip/www/key.htm). Although it is for British families, it is very thorough.